# I'm working to complete redux with typescript. How can I adjust type what I want in these actions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-actions, typesafe-actions

I just tried to use createStandardAction of typesafe-actions.
I've understand it's able to set Action, type of payload. But I wanna set actionType in action like number, string, as well using createStandardAction. 
How can I solve this problem.

```
import { createStandardAction } from 'typesafe-actions';
import { handleActions } from 'redux-actions';
import { produce } from 'immer';

const COUNT = 'workers/COUNT';
const INCREMENT = 'workers/INCREMENT';


//workersActions.count'type is any
//But I wanna this type is number. 
export const workersActions = {
  count: createStandardAction(COUNT)<number>(),
  increment: createStandardAction(INCREMENT)<void>(),
};

type Increment = ReturnType<typeof workersActions.increment>;

export type WorkerState = {
  count: number;
};

const initialState : WorkerState = {
  count : 0
}
const workers = handleActions<WorkerState, any>(
  {
    [INCREMENT]: (state, action: Increment) => {
      return produce(state, draft => {
        draft.count = action.payload + 1;
      });
    },
  },
  initialState,
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interface like this.

types.js

```
export const SEND_MESSAGE = 'SEND_MESSAGE'
export const DELETE_MESSAGE = 'DELETE_MESSAGE'

interface SendMessageAction {
  type: typeof SEND_MESSAGE
  payload: Message
}

interface DeleteMessageAction {
  type: typeof DELETE_MESSAGE
  meta: {
    timestamp: number
  }
}

export type ChatActionTypes = SendMessageAction | DeleteMessageAction
```

actions.ts

```
import { Message, SEND_MESSAGE, DELETE_MESSAGE, ChatActionTypes } from './types'

// TypeScript infers that this function is returning SendMessageAction
export function sendMessage(newMessage: Message): ChatActionTypes {
  return {
    type: SEND_MESSAGE,
    payload: newMessage
  }
}

// TypeScript infers that this function is returning DeleteMessageAction
export function deleteMessage(timestamp: number): ChatActionTypes {
  return {
    type: DELETE_MESSAGE,
    meta: {
      timestamp
    }
  }
}
```

for more details :   https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-state